# Unresolved external symbols in my x86-32 code despite linking the library

Tags: assembly, masm

I am learning x86 with Microsoft's masm and I am trying to call ExitProcess. I know this function is defined in kernel32.lib, so I linked it in my build step, doesn't work. I try do "includelib kernel32.lib" in my source code, same error. Here is the code and the command I'm using to build it:

```
.model flat, C
.stack 4096

includelib kernel32.lib
includelib user32.lib

extrn ExitProcess: proc

.code
main proc
    mov eax, 0
    ret
main endp

end main
```

and here's how I build this source code (I'm using command line tool ml.exe):

```
ml -Zi -nologo ..\code\main.asm /link -nologo -subsystem:windows User32.lib Kernel32.lib -entry:main
```

And here's the error spat out by the assembler:

```
Assembling: ..\code\main.asm
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _ExitProcess referenced in function _main
```

main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
I've searched the web extensively, but this seems to be all that's required for my code to be assembled. I just can't figure out how to get this to work. Please help.

Comment: you incorrect declare symbol. for x86 you must declare it as `extern __imp__ExitProcess@4: DWORD` for x64 - `extern __imp_ExitProcess: QWORD` and call it `call [__imp__ExitProcess@4]` for x86

Comment: any you must call `__imp__ExitProcess@4` anyway. just return from entry point can be not enough for process exit

Comment: Thanks, that works. But why do I have to add that prefix and the weird @4 in the end? I've never seen this in other x86 tutorials.

Comment: this is standard and well known x86 name mangling. you must do this or got unresolved externals

Comment: gotcha, thanks. That was really helpful. But what if I want to call other external functions? Do I just do the same thing and add "__imp__" and "@4" to their names?

Comment: and note that all imported functions - not a `proc` - this is pointer. variable. `DWORD` for 32bit and `QWORD` for 64bit

Comment: `__imp_` prefix you must add always. other depend from calling convention and platform. most api functions is `__stdcall` - for it you must add `_` at begin and `@N` at the end, where `N=4*arg_count`. `ExitProcess` have 1 agr - as result `@4`. and `call __imp__someapi@N`

Comment: Got it. very helpful; thanks a lot!

Comment: for __fastcall you add `@` in begin instead `_` at begin - say `__imp_@InterlockedPushListSList@16`. for `__cdecl` - only `_` at begin (no `@` at the end). for x64 more simply - only `__imp_`prefix added. and search interested symbol in lib file (open it even in notepad) - look how name here mangled - exactly symbol name and use in self code

Answer (score 0):

If you dont't like the weird and ugly name-mangling of exported functions, you're not alone. In my opinion functions should be invoked by the same name as they are documented, for instance in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox

I wrote a tool https://euroassembler.eu/ which is easier to use than MASM. Your program in EUROASM would look like this:

```
main program format=PE,entry=main
      import MessageBoxA,lib=user32.dll
      import ExitProcess,lib=kernel32.dll
 main proc
       push 0, ="Caption", ="Hello, world!",0 ; Msgbox requires 4 parameters.
       call MessageBoxA
       push 0                                 ; ExitProcess requires 1 parameter.
       call ExitProcess
      endp
    endprogram
```

and here's how I build main.exe from this source:

```
euroasm.exe main.asm
```